# CI is running sample yarn tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jestjs, gitlab, yarnpkg

I've relatively new to Jest and and trying to run it on my GitLab CI for a Rails app. When I run my tests locally, they run jut fine. I use this command to run them:

```
yarn run test
```

AFAIK, this is the same as running:

```
npm run test
```

When I run on the CI, the tests pass, but it is also running various sample tests from within Gems etc. See the log below.

Why am I running sample tests and how can I stop it?

```
$ yarn run test
yarn run v1.22.4
$ jest
FAIL vendor/ruby/2.7.0/gems/capybara-3.14.0/lib/capybara/spec/public/test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run
    ReferenceError: $ is not defined
      1 | var activeRequests = 0;
    > 2 | $(function() {
        | ^
      3 |   $('#change').text('I changed it');
      4 |   $('#drag, #drag_scroll, #drag_link').draggable();
      5 |   $('#drop, #drop_scroll').droppable({
      at Object.<anonymous> (vendor/ruby/2.7.0/gems/capybara-3.14.0/lib/capybara/spec/public/test.js:2:1)
PASS app/javascript/reactjs/article/AudioContent.test.js
FAIL vendor/ruby/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-5.2.1/package/environments/__tests__/base.js
  ● Environment › toWebpackConfig › should return multi file entry points
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined
      32 |     test('should return multi file entry points', () => {
      33 |       const config = environment.toWebpackConfig()
    > 34 |       expect(config.entry.multi_entry.sort()).toEqual([
         |                                       ^
      35 |         resolve('app', 'javascript', 'packs', 'multi_entry.css'),
      36 |         resolve('app', 'javascript', 'packs', 'multi_entry.js')
      37 |       ])
      at Object.<anonymous> (vendor/ruby/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-5.2.1/package/environments/__tests__/base.js:34:39)
  ● Environment › toWebpackConfig › should return default resolve.modules with additions
    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality
    - Expected  - 3
    + Received  + 0
      Array [
        "/builds/immersive-apps/immersive/app/javascript",
    -   "/builds/immersive-apps/immersive/app/assets",
    -   "/etc/yarn",
    -   "/builds/immersive-apps/immersive/app/elm",
        "node_modules",
      ]
      83 |     test('should return default resolve.modules with additions', () => {
      84 |       const config = environment.toWebpackConfig()
    > 85 |       expect(config.resolve.modules).toEqual([
         |                                      ^
      86 |         resolve('app', 'javascript'),
      87 |         resolve('app/assets'),
      88 |         resolve('/etc/yarn'),
      at Object.<anonymous> (vendor/ruby/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-5.2.1/package/environments/__tests__/base.js:85:38)
PASS vendor/ruby/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-5.2.1/package/config_types/__tests__/config_list.js
PASS app/javascript/reactjs/article/ArticleHeader.test.js
PASS vendor/ruby/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-5.2.1/package/utils/__tests__/get_style_rule.js
PASS app/javascript/reactjs/article/AudioPlayer.test.js
FAIL vendor/ruby/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-5.2.1/package/__tests__/config.js
  ● Config › should return additional paths as listed in app config, with resolved paths
    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality
    - Expected  - 5
    + Received  + 1
    - Array [
    -   "app/assets",
    -   "/etc/yarn",
    -   "app/elm",
    - ]
    + Array []
      25 | 
      26 |   test('should return additional paths as listed in app config, with resolved paths', () => {
    > 27 |     expect(config.additional_paths).toEqual(
         |                                     ^
      28 |       [
      29 |         'app/assets',
      30 |         '/etc/yarn',
      at Object.<anonymous> (vendor/ruby/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-5.2.1/package/__tests__/config.js:27:37)
  ● Config › should return extensions as listed in app config
    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality
    - Expected  - 1
    + Received  + 1
    @@ -1,6 +1,7 @@
      Array [
    +   ".jsx",
        ".mjs",
        ".js",
        ".sass",
        ".scss",
        ".css",
    @@ -10,7 +11,6 @@
        ".png",
        ".svg",
        ".gif",
        ".jpeg",
        ".jpg",
    -   ".elm",
      ]
      35 | 
      36 |   test('should return extensions as listed in app config', () => {
    > 37 |     expect(config.extensions).toEqual([
         |                               ^
      38 |       '.mjs',
      39 |       '.js',
      40 |       '.sass',
      at Object.<anonymous> (vendor/ruby/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-5.2.1/package/__tests__/config.js:37:31)
  ● Config › should return static assets extensions as listed in app config
    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality
    - Expected  - 0
    + Received  + 5
    @@ -4,6 +4,11 @@
        ".png",
        ".gif",
        ".tiff",
        ".ico",
        ".svg",
    +   ".eot",
    +   ".otf",
    +   ".ttf",
    +   ".woff",
    +   ".woff2",
      ]
      54 | 
      55 |   test('should return static assets extensions as listed in app config', () => {
    > 56 |     expect(config.static_assets_extensions).toEqual([
         |                                             ^
      57 |       '.jpg',
      58 |       '.jpeg',
      59 |       '.png',
      at Object.<anonymous> (vendor/ruby/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-5.2.1/package/__tests__/config.js:56:45)
PASS vendor/ruby/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-5.2.1/package/__tests__/dev_server.js
PASS vendor/ruby/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-5.2.1/package/__tests__/development.js
FAIL vendor/ruby/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-5.2.1/package/__tests__/env.js
  ● Env › with a non-standard environment
    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality
    - Expected  - 1
    + Received  + 1
      Object {
        "nodeEnv": "production",
    -   "railsEnv": "staging",
    +   "railsEnv": "production",
      }
      39 |     process.env.RAILS_ENV = 'staging'
      40 |     process.env.NODE_ENV = 'staging'
    > 41 |     expect(require('../env')).toEqual({
         |                               ^
      42 |       railsEnv: 'staging',
      43 |       nodeEnv: 'production'
      44 |     })
      at Object.<anonymous> (vendor/ruby/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-5.2.1/package/__tests__/env.js:41:31)
PASS vendor/ruby/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-5.2.1/package/config_types/__tests__/config_object.js
PASS vendor/ruby/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-5.2.1/package/utils/__tests__/deep_assign.js
FAIL vendor/ruby/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-5.2.1/package/__tests__/staging.js
  ● Custom environment › toWebpackConfig › should use staging config and default production environment
    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality
    Expected: "/builds/immersive-apps/immersive/public/packs-staging"
    Received: "/builds/immersive-apps/immersive/public/packs"
      19 |       const config = environment.toWebpackConfig()
      20 | 
    > 21 |       expect(config.output.path).toEqual(resolve('public', 'packs-staging'))
         |                                  ^
      22 |       expect(config.output.publicPath).toEqual('/packs-staging/')
      23 |       expect(config).toMatchObject({
      24 |         devtool: 'source-map',
      at Object.<anonymous> (vendor/ruby/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-5.2.1/package/__tests__/staging.js:21:34)
PASS vendor/ruby/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-5.2.1/package/__tests__/production.js
PASS vendor/ruby/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-5.2.1/package/__tests__/test.js
PASS vendor/ruby/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-5.2.1/package/utils/__tests__/deep_merge.js
PASS vendor/ruby/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-5.2.1/package/utils/__tests__/objectify.js
FAIL vendor/ruby/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-5.2.1/lib/install/config/webpack/test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run
    Your test suite must contain at least one test.
      at onResult (node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.js:175:18)
      at node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.js:304:17
      at node_modules/emittery/index.js:260:13
          at Array.map (<anonymous>)
      at Emittery.Typed.emit (node_modules/emittery/index.js:258:23)
FAIL vendor/ruby/2.7.0/gems/webpacker-5.2.1/package/environments/test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run
    Your test suite must contain at least one test.
      at onResult (node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.js:175:18)
      at node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.js:304:17
      at node_modules/emittery/index.js:260:13
          at Array.map (<anonymous>)
      at Emittery.Typed.emit (node_modules/emittery/index.js:258:23)
Test Suites: 7 failed, 13 passed, 20 total
Tests:       7 failed, 61 passed, 68 total
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this, but I imagine you should have some configuration for the tests to tell it to ignore any test found inside the `vendor` directory. https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testpathignorepatterns-arraystring

Comment: Just as an aside, it's generally not a great idea to move between package managers. When the package resolution happens and the lock file is written, there could easily be a situation where you have it building successfully with one package manager, and failing with another, expecially if you commit your lock files to version control. If your CI environment uses yarn, then you should probably stick to using yarn when you do your local dev.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @ShafiqJetha I am using yarn across the board. It's just strange that I don't have these problems in local but do on the CI.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add something like this to the jest section of your package.json file:

```
"jest": {
...
"testPathIgnorePatterns": [
  "<rootDir>/vendor/"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Added this to package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --verbose ./app/javascript"
  },
```

CI is running now.